# How to mirror aws ec2-instance (production) to my local ubuntu desktop

Tags: localhost, mirror

i have aws ec2-instance live server (which runs on drupal CMS), i want to make a staging server for that live on my local ubunut desktop

Comment: live server setup: LAMP, Instace is Amazon Linux

Answer (score 0):

If you uploaded ubuntu VM in AWS, Then you have option to Export that. But, No option If you take image from AWS and done the installation.

You can install same ubuntu version with webserver + php then just copy paste drupal codebase from live to local with DB then you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial details how to set up a development environment in Amazon EC2 using the AWS CLI. It includes a short version of the installation and configuration instructions, and it can be run start to finish on Windows, Linux, macOS, or Unix.

**Steps**

- Install the AWS CLI
- Configure the AWS CLI
- Create a Security Group, Key Pair, and Role for the EC2 Instance
- Launch and Connect to the Instance

*you should check this out -* 
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/tutorial-ec2-ubuntu.html